# After updating GAE Python SDK getting maximum recursion depth exceeded errors

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, runtime-error

I have an application that I've been working on since Aug 2012 and up until the last Python SDK update I'd had no problems developing locally for GAE. After the 1.7.6 release I started getting the following recursion error as soon as I launched the application:

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 218, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    request_pb.set_request(request.Encode())
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 54, in Encode
    e = Encoder()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I'm seeing this same error creating and running a blank new project directly from Google AppEngineLauncher and I've now tested and reproduced on two different machines.

Comment: I'm getting this as well with a fresh install of the Python SDK and Google App Launcher on OSX 10.8...

Comment: It appears it could be an issue with being behind a proxy. I'm testing in Firefox, and have enabled proxy-bypass for localhost and 127.0.0.1. However, my proxy server appears to be down at the moment (no other sites work).